# How to separate a single list into multiple list in python

Tags: python, list

I'm not sure if this has already been asked before, but here is what I want to do:

I have a list:

```
foods = ['I_want_ten_orange_cookies', 'I_want_four_orange_juices', 'I_want_ten_lemon_cookies', 'I_want_four_lemon_juices']
```

And I want to separate them into each individual list using the flavor, in this case which is `'orange'` and `'lemon'`:

```
orange = ['I_want_ten_orange_cookies', 'I_want_four_orange_juices']
lemon = ['I_want_ten_lemon_cookies', 'I_want_ten_lemon_juices']
```

I'm a beginner in Python, is this difficult to do?  Thank you!

Comment: No it is not. You can use either list comprehension or a for loop. I would recommend list comprehension. Give it a shot and ask us if you are stuck

Comment: Check out this resource: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
foods = ['I_want_ten_orange_cookies', 'I_want_four_orange_juices', 'I_want_ten_lemon_cookies', 'I_want_four_lemon_juices']

orange=[]
lemon=[]

for food in foods:
    if 'orange' in food.split('_'):
        orange.append(food)
    elif 'lemon' in food.split('_'):
        lemon.append(food)
```

This would output:

```
>>> orange
['I_want_ten_orange_cookies', 'I_want_four_orange_juices']

>>> lemon
['I_want_ten_lemon_cookies', 'I_want_four_lemon_juices']
```

This works if the items in the list *are always separated by underscores.*

The `if 'orange' in food.split('_')` splits the sentence into a list of words and then then checks if the food is in that list.

---

You could, in theory, just do `if 'orange' in food` but that would fail if the substring is found in another word. For example:

```
>>> s='I_appeared_there'

>>> if 'pear' in s:
    print "yes"

yes

>>> if 'pear' in s.split('_'):
    print "yes"

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foods = ['I_want_ten_orange_cookies', 'I_want_four_orange_juices', 'I_want_ten_lemon_cookies', 'I_want_four_lemon_juices']

foodlists = {'orange':[], 'lemon':[]}

for food in foods:
    for name, L in foodlists.items():
        if name in food:
            L.append(food)
```

Now, `foodlists['orange']` and `foodlists['lemon']` are the lists you are after

Comment: Wow!!!  This is exactly what I need!!  Thank you so much for your prompt answer!  I will try to integrate this into my code now.  Thank you so much!!!